# Pull URL's referral info with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a referral system for an app by adding a referral link defined as:

```
const link = `${global.origin}?ref=${address}`;
```

which returns something like
http://localhost:3000/?ref='address'

I'm struggling to find a way to get Nextjs to pull just the 'address' part of the url (and define it to be used in a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right you can use `router.query["ref"]` from Next router.